# How can I get the name of a sub folder (Thats name will vary) which I need to pass into a hard coded path to run a File.Exists

Tags: c#, file, path

I need to check if a certain file (a .config file) exist inside a given set of sub folders but I do not know what the name of these Sub folders are (As the Sub folder is named by User preference) However these sub folders will reside only inside a given directory.

How can I get the name of this sub folder to a path where I can use File.Exists to check if the file exist.

```
if (File.Exists(@ "D:\TEST\PROJ\Repo\{lastFolderName}\fileserver.config")) {
 MessageBox.Show("File Found");
} else {
 MessageBox.Show("File Not Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to try out like this

```
string path =@ "D:\TEST\PROJ\Repo\";
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();

foreach(DirectoryInfo folder in subDirectories)
{
     string subpath = Path.Combine( @ "D:\TEST\PROJ\Repo\", folder.Name);
     string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(subpath, "fileserver.config");
     if(filePaths.Any())
        Console.WriteLine(subpath);
}
```

Comment: @Sashitha yes, if you have to pass name of directory then just use this   `string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(subpath, "fileserver.config");
     if(filePaths.Any())
        Console.WriteLine(subpath);` - please do accept upvote answer if worked for you